# How to run test cases as a jar in gradle, if the test folder doesn't has a main class

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, testing, jar, executable-jar

In my gradle application I have test folder containing all the test cases, but it doesn't has a main class. In intelliJ it runs by just right clicking on folder and selecting Run

My use case is to pack that folder in a jar and run it seperately.

I used the following code in build.gradle to create executable jar

```
task testJar(type:Jar) {
    classifier='test'
    
    }
}
```

Now how do I run the jar?

All the discussions available on StackOverflow say that you need to have a main class running it  that gets added in MANIFEST.MF. Is there any other way to do it?